# Being kicked out upon logging in using ssh

Tags: ssh

Does anyone know why I am kicked out  immediately after everytime I log in? Here is the output:

> $ ssh tim@xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
>
> Password:
>
> Linux xxxx 2.6.32-24-server #43-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 16 16:05:42 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS
>
> Welcome to the Ubuntu Server!
>
> - Documentation:  http://www.ubuntu.com/server/doc
>
> You have mail.
>
> Last login: Fri Oct  1 10:24:01 2010 from xxxx.xxx.xxx
>
> You are not authorized to log into this server
>
> Connection to xxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.

If I am indeed not authorized to log into this server, why I receive the typical information upon logging in, such as the information about the server, the welcome message and the last time I logged in?

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: why don't you ask your administrator? she's the one who configured it that way (the message implies it's on purpose)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A google search shows someone might be using this script :-)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1545205

The default shell is replaced by a script looking for the username in an “allowed users“ file and either starts a standard bash or displays this message and exits.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because your shell has been switched to something that prints that message and exits afterwards. In that case, SSH will behave just as usual and display any welcome message, biff, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Has the software on the server been updated recently?

Some idiot package maintainers ( and Ubuntu is one of the big violators ), decide that they know better then you what settings  you should have and overwrite them.