# Is my default remote shell a trouble maker?

Tags: ssh

By `finger tim` on the server, I learned that my default shell is some script `/usr/local/bin/bash-wrapper` whose content is:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=`whoami`

if ! grep ^$USERNAME$ /etc/domain-users > /dev/null; then
   echo -e "You are not authorized to log into this server\n\n"
elif test -z "$2"; then
   echo -e "User authorized"
   /bin/bash
else #in case users are trying to send a command via ssh or use scp
   $2
fi
```

I now understand the script is the cause of me previously [being kicked out upon logging in using ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2583/being-kicked-out-upon-logging-in-using-ssh). The problem is now gone, because I was just recently added to that file `/etc/domain-users` which `grep` is searching in.

Now my questions are:

1. What does the script do if I send a command for the server shell to
   run in the same line as `ssh`, such as the following two questions Part 2 and Part 3?
2. Is it the cause of [the failure of my copy of public key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29386/how-do-you-copy-the-public-key-to-a-ssh-server):

   ```
   $ cat /home/tim/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh tim@server 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
   Password: 
   cat: >>: No such file or directory
   cat: .ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
   ```

   I also tried `ssh-copy-id`, but it doesn't work either:

   ```
   $ ssh-copy-id tim@server
   Password: 
   /usr/local/bin/bash-wrapper: line 11: umask: 077;: octal number out of range
   ```
3. The following ssh-tunneling command doesn't run well from my local
   either:

   ```
   ssh -f -D 9999 tim@server "if [ -f ~/.tunnel ]; then rm ~/.tunnel; fi; while [ ! -f ~/.tunnel ]; do echo > /dev/null; done"
   ```

   Here is the error that I get

   ```
   /usr/local/bin/bash-wrapper: line 11: if: command not found
   ```

   I wonder why?
4. My login is always very slow. Is it because the `grep` takes
   time? Note that the file `/etc/domain-users`in which `grep` searches has 199 lines and each line is a username. Is it supposed to take long for `grep` to do  its job?
5. How can I change my default shell?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Tell your admin that that is an incredibly bad (and stupid) way of authenticating users. Plus the script is all sorts of broken (as dr jimbob pointed out in his answer). The proper way of doing this is to use the `pam_access` module. Its designed for EXACTLY this purpose.

Comment: @Patrick: Thanks for the advice! I feel difficult to inform my supervisor his way is bad.

Comment: Ok, you can leave out telling him its crap :-P. Just say that its causing you problems and point out the `pam_access` module (http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_access).

Comment: defo. this method of authentication seems like madness.

Comment: @Patrick You really should tell someone why its a bad idea instead of just saying its bad and stupid. People don't react well to being told their way is stupid and then close themselves off to your reasons for why the idea is stupid. So maybe you should explain why its a bad idea and educate everyone.

Comment: @deltaray I did. The script is all sorts of broken (as dr jimbob pointed out in his answer). The proper way of doing this is to use the pam_access module. Its designed for EXACTLY this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grepping through a 200 line file should take millisecond or so, so I would doubt its that.

Try `ssh -vvv tim@server` to see what's slowing it down.

Your default shell is saved in `/etc/passwd` at the end of your line:

```
drjimbob:x:1000:1000:jim bob,,,:/home/drjimbob:/bin/bash
```

and can be changed by `chsh tim -s /bin/bash` (change shell) <s>though you typically have to have root privileges to change your default shell</s>, which you can do if you have your user's password (you do not need root permission).

Note, that `/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id` is just a script and the line that's getting you in trouble is:

```
{ eval "$GET_ID" ; } | ssh ${1%:} "umask 077; test -d .ssh || mkdir .ssh ; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys" || exit 1
```

If you test this; with a script like test_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

umask 077; echo "Works fine"
$2
```

and run it like `bash -v -x test_script.sh "ignored_first_parameter" "umask 077; echo 'no'"`

You'll see that the bash tokenization (based on the environmental variable `$IFS`) of the variable "umask 077; echo no" into the second parameter and then shell expansion told bash to run the command `umask '077;'` which gives the error.

It's basically due to the fact that typing into bash `command1; command2` is fundamentally different than setting a variable `some_var='command1; command2"` and then running `$some_var`.

See: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

---

EDIT: To address your specific questions;

(1) I still think this method of access control is suspect and possibly circumvented by one of the standard tricks if a user has some other sort of access.  Let's say they have ftp access to their user directory; they could potentially upload a .login file (containing a fake $PATH and a fake whoami) that lets them login.

At the very least the script should specify the full path of `whoami` (on my ubuntu machine its `/usr/bin/whoami`; may vary on different systems).  See: [Secure Programming for Linux Ch 5.2](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/environment-variables.html).

It seems cleaner to disable the shell for users who can't login (e.g., set the shell to `/bin/false` in `/etc/passwd` for users not in your list).  Alternatively (or additionally), if you are only worried about remote logins, possibly use a setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to use some combination of `AllowUsers/AllowGroups` to whitelist users/groups or `DenyUsers/DenyGroups` to blacklist users/groups to ssh (though noting that these users could login if the have physical access to the machine).

However, if your supervisor modified their script to use `eval $2` it should fix the immediate issues with ssh-copy-id.  See [Bash: why use eval with variable expansion](http://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Why_use_eval_with_variable_expansion%3F).

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=`whoami`

if ! grep ^$USERNAME$ /etc/domain-users > /dev/null; then
 echo -e "You are not authorized to log into this server\n\n"
elif test -z "$2"; then
 echo -e "User authorized"
 /bin/bash
else #in case users are trying to send a command via ssh or use scp
 eval $2
fi
```

For questions 2-5; the answers, (2) yes, (3) yes, (4) no, (5) `chsh tim -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks! I have upload the output to [here](http://pastebin.com/A9Lpmh6Z). I found that each of  three lines are particularly slow. Please see my new post [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29414/what-slows-down-my-ssh-login). Thanks!

Comment: @Tim - Hey made some changes (e.g., how your supervisor can fix his script; how you can just change your shell; and better methods for the supervisor to do access-control).

Comment: Thanks! I tried `chsh tim -s /bin/bash`, but `You may not change the shell for 'tim'.`

Comment: Apparently, the supervisor setup PAM to limit normal users from using chsh.  See last paragraph: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chsh