# What slows down my ssh login?

Tags: ssh

Every time I ssh login to a server, it is always very slow. As [a reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29399/674) to [my earlier post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29395/is-my-default-remote-shell-a-trouble-maker) said, "grepping through a 200 line file should take millisecond or so, so I would doubt it's that."

I tried `ssh -vvv time@server` and the output has been uploaded [here](http://pastebin.com/A9Lpmh6Z). I found that when proceeding to each of these three lines in the output, it is particularly slow:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic 

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found 


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_1000' not found
```

I wonder why and what I can do to change it? Thanks and regards!

---

Update:

Ignacio's reply suggests me to "disable all GSS/Kerberos auth methods in your configuration."

So in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, do I have to make sure "no" is behind each of all options starting with "GSS": GSSAPIAuthentication, GSSAPIDelegateCredentials, GSSAPIKeyExchange, GSSAPITrustDNS, GSSAPIAuthentication, and GSSAPIDelegateCredentials?

Then what are the options for "Kerberos" auth method that I need to put "no" behind?

PS: following is the content of my local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` with commented options not copied to here:

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29395

Comment: @PaulTomblin: Not many. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to speed my too-slow ssh login?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5621/how-to-speed-my-too-slow-ssh-login)

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks, I fixed my problem from that post. Before I had to wait the cursor to flash 30 times, now it takes the cursor to flash 7 times. (1) Is it now a normal speed to wait the cursor to flash 7 times? (2) Why does it work by commenting out     `GSSAPIAuthentication yes` and `GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no`?

Comment: [Here is an answer that addresses a possible cause for slow down.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318640/130579)

Answer (score 15):

> ```
> debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
> ```

That's Kerberos. Disable all GSS/Kerberos auth methods in your configuration. See the `ssh_config(5)` man page, `PreferredAuthentications` option, for more details.

Comment: Thanks! By "your configuration", you mean my local one or the remote server's?

Comment: `PreferredAuthentications` is on the client. On the server, use `GSSAPIAuthentication` instead.

Comment: Thanks! So in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, (1) do I have to make sure "no" is behind each of all options starting with "GSS": GSSAPIAuthentication, GSSAPIDelegateCredentials, GSSAPIKeyExchange, GSSAPITrustDNS, GSSAPIAuthentication, and GSSAPIDelegateCredentials? 
(2) what are the options for "Kerberos" auth method that I need to put "no" behind?

PS: I just updated my post with the content of my local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: 1) Modifying `PreferredAuthentications` is enough. 2. Kerberos uses GSS; disabling GSS is enough.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask how to modify PreferredAuthentications? I cannot find it in ssh_config(5) manpage

Comment: Which version are you running that doesn't have it?

Comment: ssh version is `OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu6, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010`. I can't find `PreferredAuthentications` in my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file for me to modify.

Comment: I put `PreferredAuthentications no` in my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, but it doesn't work because of`Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive).`

Comment: Thank you; you solved my debilitating problem waiting 60 seconds to SSH into RedHat servers.

Comment: Leverage the SSH **client** config.d directory: Create a file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/10-gssapiauthentication-no.conf` with the following content: `GSSAPIAuthentication no` ... And notice this is with directory */etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*, ... **not** */etc/ssh/ssh**d**_config.d/* ... Because this is an SSH **client** configuration, **not** an SSH **server** configuration.

Answer (score 3):

`UseDNS no` and `CheckHostIP no` should speed up things, too.

It is also a good security measure to allow protocol 2 only.
If you don't need IPv6 disable it (AddressFamily).

Answer (score 1):

Could it be ssh/etc/ssh_prng_cmds?  There is a job in ssh that runs a series of commands to make stuff random as you log in.  One of those commands is probably taking too long because it is doing something that is silly on your computer.  The only thing I can think of now is that ssh requires the computer to cut down the largest tree in the forest with......

a HERRING.

So "run" some of these commands from a prompt and find out with one takes a long time to respond.  Comment out THAT one.

Answer (score 1):

For me I needed GSSAPI and I didn't want to turn off reverse DNS lookups, that just didn't seem like a good idea so I checked out the man page for resolv.conf.  It turns out that a firewall between me and the servers I was SSHing to was interfering with DNS requests because they weren't in a form that the firewall expected.  In the end all I needed to do was add this line to resolv.conf on the servers that I was SSHing to -

options single-request-reopen​

Comment: For anyone investigating similar problems, see also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141278/23367