# slow ssh login to a remote machine

Tags: ssh, solaris, sshd

I am experiencing slow ssh login from a machine to a remote machine.
The verbose of ssh is shown below in two broken blocks. ssh freezes for 15 seconds in the below shown block.

```
[root@zabbix ~]# ssh -vvv zabbix@172.18.xxx.xx
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 172.18.xxx.xx [172.18.xxx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Sun_SSH_1.1.4
debug1: no match: Sun_SSH_1.1.4
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
...............
...............
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 96 bytes for a total of 1205
```

ssh hangs here for approx 15 seconds and then it asks for the password

```
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
```

After password input, it hangs at the end of the line shown below:

```
debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 23 padlen 9 extra_pad 64)
debug3: Wrote 80 bytes for a total of 1285
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1349
```

After approx 15 seconds, login is done successfully.

**My question is, what can I do to make this ssh attempt faster?**

This login attempt is done from a RHEL 6.2 machine to a Solaris 10 machine.
At the very first moment I thought that it could be a network issue but later I found that I could login without any such freezes from an another Solaris 10 machine to the same remote Solaris machine I mentioned above.

The version of SSH in the remote Solaris machine is shown below:

```
$ ssh -V
Sun_SSH_1.1.4, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x0090704f
```

While the version of SSH in RHEL machine is shown below:

```
[root@zabbix ~]# ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
```

Please note that the remote Solaris 10 machine is a zone on Physical solaris 10 machine.
Attempt to login using ssh to the Physical solaris 10 machine is very fast from the local RHEL machine. So, I suppose, this is not network issue at all.

**Update**: Adding below all enabled directives in sshd_config file in the remote Solaris 10 machine.

```
Protocol 2
Port 22
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
PrintMotd no
KeepAlive yes
SyslogFacility auth
LogLevel info
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
ServerKeyBits 768
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
StrictModes yes
LoginGraceTime 600
MaxAuthTries    6
MaxAuthTriesLog 3
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes
PAMAuthenticationViaKBDInt yes
Subsystem   sftp    internal-sftp
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsAuthentication no
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
RSAAuthentication yes
```

Your input is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why SSH takes a long time to Connect](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65068/why-ssh-takes-a-long-time-to-connect)

Comment: But the logs aren't the same in both of the posts. So, the cause of the delay in ssh i am observing is not answered over there.

Comment: Do you observe the same delay if you authenticate with a key? What user authentication methods are specified in the server configuration? If PAM is used, how is it configured?

Comment: As suggested by you, I tried the key based authentication, and unfortunately the speed of logging in still the same. :( I am going to update my post and add the excerpt from sshd_config file of the remote Solaris 10 machine.

Comment: @Gilles: I have added excerpt from sshd_config file. Is this what you wanted to look? Please let me know if you want any more information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the RHEL machine, try:

```
ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no zabbix@172.18.xxx.xx
```

If that works, make it permanent by editing `~/.ssh/config` and add:

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Also, check that the RHEL is visible in DNS (from the server's point of view).  The server tries to check your reverse DNS resolution. If that fails, you'll suffer a delay.

This check can be disabled:

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

OpenSSH: Use `UseDNS no`

Solaris: Use `LookupClientHostnames no`

Restart `sshd` and it should be quicker to log on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "GSSAPIAuthentication no" did not work. The other explanation shows some light on this delay. I could not find any "UseDNS" directive in the sshd_config of the remote Solaris machine. It was not mentioned in the manual also. Howerver, there is a similar directive as "LookupClientHostnames". I would try to change its value to no and let you know about the result.

Comment: That sounds like the equivalent Solaris.  If you can confirm that, I'll edit the post for future readers.

Comment: Sure. That would be my pleasure. But system admin has left office and they can only change the value and confirm me back about the result :) .

Comment: Thanks @garethTheRed :) I added "LookupClientHostnames no" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file of the remote Solaris 10 zone and restarted sshd (svcadm restart network/ssh) and ssh login became swifter. Thanks a ton again :)

Comment: Thanks so much for adding the Solaris variant! That helped a lot. You saved me a lot of hassle time and headache at a time I could not afford another bit rathole / diversion.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was with the /etc/resolv.conf - wrong domains to search upon, as well as non-existent DNS servers to provide lookups.  Surprised I was able to login at all.