# Resolving hostname takes 5 seconds

Tags: debian, dns, ipv6, bind, nslookup

I've a master `bind9` DNS server and 2 slave servers running on IPv4 (Debian Jessie), using `/etc/bind/named.conf`:

```
listen-on-v6 { none; };
```

When I try to connect from different server(s) each connection takes at least 5 seconds (I'm using [Joseph's timing info](https://blog.josephscott.org/2011/10/14/timing-details-with-curl/) for debugging):

```
$ curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s https://example.com
            time_namelookup:  5.512
               time_connect:  5.512
            time_appconnect:  5.529
           time_pretransfer:  5.529
              time_redirect:  0.000
         time_starttransfer:  5.531
                            ----------
                 time_total:  5.531
```

According to `curl`, lookup takes most of the time, however standard `nslookup` is very fast:

```
$ time nslookup example.com > /dev/null 2>&1

real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.000s
```

After forcing `curl` to use IPv4, it gets much better:

```
$ curl -4 -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s https://example.com

            time_namelookup:  0.004
               time_connect:  0.005
            time_appconnect:  0.020
           time_pretransfer:  0.020
              time_redirect:  0.000
         time_starttransfer:  0.022
                            ----------
                 time_total:  0.022
```

I've disabled IPv6 on the host:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/disable_ipv6
```

though the problem persists. I've tried running `strace` to see what's the reason of timeouts:

```
write(2, "*", 1*)                        = 1
write(2, " ", 1 )                        = 1
write(2, "Hostname was NOT found in DNS ca"..., 36Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
) = 36
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
close(4)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f220bcf8000
mprotect(0x7f220bcf8000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7f220c4f7fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f220c4f89d0, tls=0x7f220c4f8700, child_tidptr=0x7f220c4f89d0) = 2004
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
poll(0, 0, 4)                           = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
poll(0, 0, 8)                           = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
poll(0, 0, 16)                          = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
poll(0, 0, 32)                          = 0 (Timeout)
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f22102e08d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
poll(0, 0, 64)                          = 0 (Timeout)
```

It doesn't seem to be a firewall issues as `nslookup` (or `curl -4`) is using the same DNS servers. Any idea what could be wrong?

Here's `tcpdump` from the host `tcpdump -vvv -s 0 -l -n port 53`:

```
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:14:52.542526 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 35839, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 63)
    192.168.1.1.59163 > 192.168.1.2.53: [bad udp cksum 0xf9f3 -> 0x96c7!] 39535+ A? example.com. (35)
20:14:52.542540 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 35840, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 63)
    192.168.1.1.59163 > 192.168.1.2.53: [bad udp cksum 0xf9f3 -> 0x6289!] 45997+ AAAA? example.com. (35)
20:14:52.543281 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 61, id 63674, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 158)
    192.168.1.2.53 > 192.168.1.1.59163: [udp sum ok] 45997* q: AAAA? example.com. 1/1/0 example.com. [1h] CNAME s01.example.com. ns: example.com. [10m] SOA ns01.example.com. ns51.domaincontrol.com. 2016062008 28800 7200 1209600 600 (130)
20:14:57.547439 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 36868, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 63)
    192.168.1.1.59163 > 192.168.1.2.53: [bad udp cksum 0xf9f3 -> 0x96c7!] 39535+ A? example.com. (35)
20:14:57.548188 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 61, id 64567, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 184)
    192.168.1.2.53 > 192.168.1.1.59163: [udp sum ok] 39535* q: A? example.com. 2/2/2 example.com. [1h] CNAME s01.example.com., s01.example.com. [1h] A 136.243.154.168 ns: example.com. [30m] NS ns01.example.com., example.com. [30m] NS ns02.example.com. ar: ns01.example.com. [1h] A 136.243.154.168, ns02.example.com. [1h] A 192.168.1.2 (156)
20:14:57.548250 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 36869, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 63)
    192.168.1.1.59163 > 192.168.1.2.53: [bad udp cksum 0xf9f3 -> 0x6289!] 45997+ AAAA? example.com. (35)
20:14:57.548934 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 61, id 64568, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 158)
    192.168.1.2.53 > 192.168.1.1.59163: [udp sum ok] 45997* q: AAAA? example.com. 1/1/0 example.com. [1h] CNAME s01.example.com. ns: example.com. [10m] SOA ns01.example.com. ns51.domaincontrol.com. 2016062008 28800 7200 1209600 600 (130)
```

**EDIT:**
In bind logs frequently appears this message:

```
error sending response: host unreachable
```

Though, each query is eventually answered (it just takes 5s). All machines are physical servers (it's not fault of NAT), it's more likely that packets are being blocked by a router. Here's quite likely related question: [DNS lookups sometimes take 5 seconds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141163/dns-lookups-sometimes-take-5-seconds).

Comment: `strace -tt` would make the trace more informative when tracking down delays.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't help much in this case. It seems to be stuck in a look while retrying same connection with increasing timeout `poll(0, 0, 1000)  = 0 (Timeout)`. On the DNS server side I'm getting frequent errors `error sending response: host unreachable` which looks like the outgoing packet is blocked (but not for `nslookup`).

Comment: This looks similar- http://www.philippecloutier.com/blogpost28-dig-1-and-other-DNS-clients-sometimes-taking-5-seconds-to-return-the-results-of-a-local-query

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short answer:**

A workaround is forcing `glibc` to reuse a socket for look up of the `AAAA` and `A` records, by adding a line to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
options single-request-reopen
```

The real cause of this issue might be:

- malconfigured firewall or a router (e.g. a [Juniper firewall configuration described here](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB12312&actp=RSS)) which causes dropping `AAAA` DNS packets
- bug in DNS server

**Long answer:**

Programs like `curl` or `wget` use glibc's function [getaddrinfo()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html), which tries to be compatible with both IPv4 and IPv6 by looking up both DNS records in parallel. It doesn't return result until both records are received (there are [several issues related to such behaviour](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=505105)) - this explains the `strace` above. When IPv4 is forced, like `curl -4` internally `gethostbyname()` which queries for `A` record only.

From `tcpdump` we can see that:

- `-> A?` two requests are send at the beginning
- `-> AAAA?` (requesting IPv6 address)
- `<- AAAA` reply
- `-> A?` requesting again IPv4 address
- `<- A` got reply
- `-> AAAA?` requesting IPv6 again
- `<- AAAA` reply

One `A` reply gets dropped for some reason, that's this error message:

```
error sending response: host unreachable
```

Yet it's unclear to me why there's a need for second `AAAA` query.

To verify that you're having the same issue you can update timeout in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
options timeout:3
```

First create a text file with [custom time reporting config](https://blog.josephscott.org/2011/10/14/timing-details-with-curl/):

```
cat >./curl-format.txt  <<-EOF
   time_namelookup: %{time_namelookup}\n
      time_connect: %{time_connect}\n
   time_appconnect: %{time_appconnect}\n
     time_redirect: %{time_redirect}\n
  time_pretransfer: %{time_pretransfer}\n
time_starttransfer: %{time_starttransfer}\n
                    ----------\n
time_total: %{time_total}\n
EOF
```

then send a request:

```
$ curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s https://example.com

            time_namelookup:  3.511
               time_connect:  3.511
            time_appconnect:  3.528
           time_pretransfer:  3.528
              time_redirect:  0.000
         time_starttransfer:  3.531
                            ----------
                 time_total:  3.531
```

There are two other related options in `man resolv.conf`:

> **single-request (since glibc 2.10)** sets `RES_SNGLKUP`  in  `_res.options`.   By default, glibc performs IPv4 and IPv6 lookups in parallel since version 2.9. Some appliance DNS servers cannot handle these queries properly and make the requests time out.  This option disables the
> behavior and makes glibc perform the IPv6 and IPv4 requests sequentially (at the cost of some slowdown of the resolving
> process).
>
> **single-request-reopen (since glibc 2.9)**
> The  resolver  uses  the same socket for the A and AAAA requests.  Some hardware mistakenly sends back only one
> reply.  When
> that happens the client system will sit and wait for the second reply.  Turning this option on changes this behavior so
> that
> if  two requests from the same port are not handled correctly it will close the socket and open a new one before
> sending the
> second request.

Related issues:

- [DNS lookups sometimes take 5 seconds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141163/dns-lookups-sometimes-take-5-seconds)
- [Delay associated with AAAA request](https://serverfault.com/questions/705629/delay-associated-with-aaaa-request)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Solely based on the up-voltes it seemed that users found the other answer more helpful. No offense meant.

Answer (score 5):

As @Tombart says, the delay is due to waiting for the IPv6 resolution timeout.

Another possible course of action is giving precedence to IPv4 in /etc/gai.conf

From comments in /etc/gai.conf

> ```
> #   For sites which prefer IPv4 connections change the last line to
> #
> precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
> ```

After changing `gai.conf`, you need to restart any app using the DNS resolver library for the change to take effect.

Mind you that if you are using a BIND server without IPv6 connectivity, I advise disabling IPv6 in `named` and taking from the root hints IPv6 addresses. Obviously it will still try to resolve AAAA addresses.

So for the BIND configuration,

In /etc/default/bind9, add -4 for IPv4 addresses:

```
OPTIONS="-4 -u bind"
```

and in `/etc/bind/db.root`, delete all lines with AAAA DNS roots.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while using BIND9. To fix this I needed to add:

```
filter-aaaa-on-v4 yes;
```

option to my `named.conf`.

([More information](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00576/0/Filter-AAAA-option-in-BIND-9-.html))

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved for me after starting to use `systemd-resolved`. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-resolved

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackex
change.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.

Comment: The link is just optional. The answer is to use systemd-resolved. The installing process depends on the Linux distribution in use.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for the curl-format.txt. Paste this into your shell and it will create the format file for you. The original link didn't work for me. found this example [here](https://chowdera.com/2021/01/20210127075116377F.html)

```
cat >./curl-format.txt  <<-EOF
   time_namelookup: %{time_namelookup}\n
      time_connect: %{time_connect}\n
   time_appconnect: %{time_appconnect}\n
     time_redirect: %{time_redirect}\n
  time_pretransfer: %{time_pretransfer}\n
time_starttransfer: %{time_starttransfer}\n
                    ----------\n
time_total: %{time_total}\n
EOF
```